# Serenity passing wrong definition to parameters

Tags: java, functional-testing, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I believe the issue is with serenity. The Problem is that in my story file I have my definitions that have worked all up until recently, but now when serenity parses my story file the definition it checks for is incorrect.

**Story File**

```
Given the following comment information to be added:
| comment-Id | comment-type | Text      |
| 121        | New          | longText1 |
```

**Definition**

```
@Given("the following comment information to be added: $commentsTable")
public void givenTheCommentInformation(final ExamplesTable commentsTable) {
       steps.givenCommentInformation(commentsTable);
}
```

Now here's the issue

```
[pool-1-thread-1] ERROR net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - TEST FAILED AT STEP Given the following comment information to be added: | comment-Id | comment-type | Text | | 121 | New | longText1 |
[pool-1-thread-1] ERROR net.thucydides.core.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - 

org.jbehave.core.io.StoryResourceNotFound: Story path 'to be added:
| comment-Id | comment-type | Text      |
| 121        | New          | longText1 |' not found by class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@135fbaa4
    at org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath.resourceAsStream(LoadFromClasspath.java:82)
    at org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath.loadResourceAsText(LoadFromClasspath.java:66)
    at org.jbehave.core.model.ExamplesTableFactory.createExamplesTable(ExamplesTableFactory.java:76)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.ParameterConverters$ExamplesTableConverter.convertValue(ParameterConverters.java:769)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.ParameterConverters$ExamplesTableConverter.convertValue(ParameterConverters.java:759)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.ParameterConverters.convert(ParameterConverters.java:227)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator.convertParameterValues(StepCreator.java:421)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator.access$1400(StepCreator.java:48)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$ParametrisedStep.parametriseStep(StepCreator.java:844)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$ParametrisedStep.perform(StepCreator.java:786)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$FineSoFar.run(PerformableTree.java:349)
```

Ok now if you look at this. You can see the path is incomplete, it starts at `'to be added:'` I've never had this issue before any help is much appreciated.

```
org.jbehave.core.io.StoryResourceNotFound: Story path 'to be added:
    | comment-Id | comment-type | Text      |
    | 121        | New          | longText1 |' not found by class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@135fbaa4
```

Comment: Do you have another step, like, `@Given("the following comment information $someVariable")` ?

Comment: @VaL No, all my steps have different strings. I believe it's pulling the wrong path because when I've gotten this error before I think it's supposed to show the whole string.

Comment: The error in the post is from Jenkins, I can't replicate the error locally.

Comment: how to do run tests on Jenkins?

Comment: @VaL You were right. I finally found the step I was using a find in path and I was in the wrong folder. You run Jenkins test with a Jenkins script and I use maven.